# How to measure package installation on windows terminal?

Tags: powershell, installation, cmd, terminal, package

I want track a package install time like: `time yarn create react-app appname` but the time command isn't working in my terminal.

Comment: What is "my terminal"? and why have you assigned tags for both cmd.exe and powershell.exe? What is "the time command"? Your question is not currently suitable for this site because you have not provided any problem code, or submitted sufficient information for us to reproduce your situation. Please use the [edit] button and make the required improvements to allow your question to be answered with focus on a specific programming problem. Please note that we do not offer a free code writing service, so do not expect us to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Measure-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7.2), but note that it eats your Output and returns a Timespan Object  `Measure-Command { yarn create react-app appname }`

In this case I would use a Stopwatch

```
$watch = [system.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
yarn create react-app appname
$watch.Stop()
$watch
```

Comment: in principle correct, but you can access the output of ```yarn create react-app appname``` in combination with measure-command by storing the output in a varibale, e.g. ```measure-command {output = yarn create react-app appname}```